# React Re-Rendering Unexpected Behavior

Tags: reactjs

Below is code snippet

```
const MuiSelect = () => {

    const [country , setCountry] = useState('')
    console.log("C1: " + country)
    const handleChange = (event : React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      setCountry(event.target.value as string)
      console.log("C2: " + country);
    }

  return (
    <Box width="250px">
        <TextField label="Select country"
         select 
        value={country} 
        onChange={handleChange}
        fullWidth>
            <MenuItem value="PK">Pakistan</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="US">United States</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="SA">Saudi Arabia</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="IR">Iran</MenuItem>
        </TextField>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

In `C1` I am getting updated value when component render/re-render. But in `C2` I am getting old/previous state of the country. I am having difficult time to understand this. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2):

When setting the state with `useState` there is no guarantee that it will be set [instantly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069332/9016625). That's why I think you see the old state in `C2`, because the state has not been set.

You may use a useEffect to log the updated state name

```js
useEffect(()=>{
   console.log("Updated country", country);
}, [country])
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the updated value of state, a component has to re-render. In your case when you are updating the state, first your component complete the handlechange function call and then it updates the state where you see C1 with updated state.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you need store some mutable value u can use React.createRef().
But ref change will not trigger component re-render.

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't update state immediately.
React changes states when re-rendering.
In order to perform efficiently, re-rendering occurs just one time lazily when there are a number of states changing in the one event.
This is called `"batch update"` in React.

C1 variable in logs has been already changed after rendering.

So timely, C2(before change in event) - Rerendering - C1(after change)

Here is a good post for you.

- [Why React doesn’t update state immediately](https://blog.logrocket.com/why-react-doesnt-update-state-immediately/)